# Как сделать, чтобы окно все время было активным на Java?

Tags: java

Есть окно JFrame, которое должно всегда быть в фокусе. Каким образом этого можно достичь? Такие вещи как:

```
this.setFocusable(true);
this.requestFocus();
this.toFront();
```

не делают окно активным, если оно потеряло активность. Если нельзя делать средствами Java - то вариант с WinAPI тоже подошел бы.

На C# это задача решается при помощи:

```
this.Activate();
this.TopLevel = true;
this.TopMost = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет JNA+WinAPI, приведу пример как сделать окно поверх всех окон. В этом примере я работаю с запущенным приложением Калькулятор из набора Windows. Вы можете получить хэндле окна любым другим удобным для Вас способом.

```
package test.jna;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

public class testjna {
public interface MyUser32  extends User32 {
    static final MyUser32 instance=(MyUser32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", MyUser32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    public boolean SetWindowPos(HWND hwnd, int hwnd2, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int flags);
    public int EnableWindow(HWND hwnd, boolean enabled);
}
    public static void main(String[] params){
        HWND tst= MyUser32.instance.FindWindow(null, "Калькулятор");
        MyUser32.instance.SetWindowPos(tst, -1, 200, 200, 100, 100, 0x0040|0x0002|0x0001);
        MyUser32.instance.EnableWindow(tst, true);
    }
}
```

Если вам нужно модальное окно, из которого нельзя вернутся назад (ну например как выбор файла или диалоговое окно), то вам нужно задать всем родителям этого окна значение enabled в false (нет такого параметра у окна "модальность", но если у него все родители не активны, то из него нельзя переключиться).
Для изменения активности есть функция EnableWindow.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Все работает - отлично! Теперь понятно как из Java работать с WinAPI.

Answer (score 3):

```
 frame.setAlwaysOnTop( true );
 frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Буду знать о существовании этих методов. Но результат у них не такой как с использованием WinAPI. Мне нужно было сделать поздравительный блокировщик Windows - чтобы окно сразу перекрывало, вызываемый диспетчер задач. Через WinAPI этого удается добиться, а через эти два метода нет, хотя на C# подобных средств было достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

На нужный фрейм вешается слушатель. Как только теряет фокус, делает его активным и поверх всех окон. Таким образом все время на него переключает. Соответственно закрытие фрейма крестиком или кнопкой - не производит эффекта возврата к окну, т.к. оно закрыто.

```
// Сворачивание окна фрейма
    public class iconifiedListener implements WindowListener {
        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
             System.out.println("windowActivated");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
             System.out.println("windowClosed");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
             System.out.println("windowClosing");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
             frame.setFocusable(true);
             frame.toFront();
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
             System.out.println("windowDeiconified");
        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
             System.out.println("windowIconified");

        }

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
             System.out.println("windowOpened");
        }
    }
```